# How to use R littler with docker to install installable source files?

Tags: r, littler

I would like to install some specific version of a R package. According to the documentation littler recognise installable source files. So I assumed that may work:

```
FROM r-base:latest

RUN apt-get update \
      && install.r --error digest_0.6.8.tar.gz
```

The output looks as follows and at least here does not contradict my assumption

```
            [+] Building 9.3s (6/6) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                              
            => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                     0.0s
            => => transferring dockerfile: 138B                                                                                                                                                     0.0s
            => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                        0.0s
            => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                          0.0s
            => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/r-base:latest                                                                                                                         0.3s
            => CACHED [1/2] FROM docker.io/library/r-base:latest@sha256:c3808f786a44ef1b2ed727166ac3daed1d47b1894c6858869a2bb6f97b7a1da9                                                            0.0s

            => [2/2] RUN apt-get update         && install.r --error digest_0.6.8.tar.gz                                                                                                            8.7s
            => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                   0.2s
            => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                  0.2s
            => => writing image sha256:a8781141095c3edef0618ebf1b2be8de435cdc62eacae6c617f2b512c7df68f5                                                                                             0.0s 
            => => naming to docker.io/library/test_install_r
```

However when running the container `digest` is not installed.

When using install2.r

```
FROM r-base:latest

RUN apt-get update \
      && install2.r --error digest_0.6.8.tar.gz
```

where throws an error:

```
        => ERROR [2/2] RUN apt-get update         && install2.r --error digest_0.6.8.tar.gz                                                                                                     8.3s
        ------                                                                                                                                                                                        
        > [2/2] RUN apt-get update         && install2.r --error digest_0.6.8.tar.gz:                                                                                                                
        #5 0.440 Get:1 http://deb.debian.org/debian testing InRelease [129 kB]                                                                                                                        
        #5 0.537 Ign:2 https://eddelbuettel.github.io/ppaR400 ./ InRelease                                                                                                                            
        #5 0.669 Get:3 http://deb.debian.org/debian experimental InRelease [75.4 kB]                                                                                                                  
        #5 0.711 Get:4 https://eddelbuettel.github.io/ppaR400 ./ Release [1,204 B]                                                                                                                    
        #5 0.822 Get:5 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian sid InRelease [165 kB]
        #5 0.826 Get:6 http://deb.debian.org/debian testing/main amd64 Packages [8,260 kB]
        #5 0.837 Ign:7 https://eddelbuettel.github.io/ppaR400 ./ Release.gpg
        #5 0.980 Get:8 https://eddelbuettel.github.io/ppaR400 ./ Packages [26.4 kB]
        #5 1.144 Get:9 http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian sid/main amd64 Packages [8,881 kB]
        #5 3.522 Get:10 http://deb.debian.org/debian experimental/main amd64 Packages [392 kB]
        #5 5.783 Fetched 17.9 MB in 5s (3,289 kB/s)
        #5 5.783 Reading package lists...
        #5 8.186 Error: package ‘digest_0.6.8.tar.gz’ is not available for this version of R
        #5 8.186 
        #5 8.186 A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
        #5 8.186 see the ideas at
        #5 8.186 https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
        #5 8.186 In addition: Warning message:
        #5 8.186 package ‘digest_0.6.8.tar.gz’ is not available for this version of R
        #5 8.186 
        #5 8.186 A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
        #5 8.186 see the ideas at
        #5 8.186 https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
```

I guess Im missing something here and appreciate any suggestions!